# How much requests Heroku can handle for PHP

Tags: php, heroku

According to official heroku website a dyno can handle thousands of requests per second depending on language used. I am using PHP. Can you explain how much requests can its one dyno handle?

Are all of my applications are using same dyno or each uses separate one?

Comment: I'm using Laravel Octane (Swoole) and it can handle at least 170 requests per second on Heroku with one dyno. https://github.com/cachewerk/heroku-php-extensions

Answer (score 1):

Direct from the [Heroku dev](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos) center:

> A single-threaded, non-concurrent framework like Rails can process one
>   request at a time. For an app that takes 100ms on average to process
>   each request, this translates to about 10 requests per second per
>   dyno.
>
> Load testing your app is the only realistic way to determine request
>   throughput.

If you are using something that is event drive, like Node.js, more requests would be handled.